# Independent distribution from Normal and Cauchy distribution

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

tfp.distributions.Independent can be used to sample from multivariate distributions where each dimension is independent (e.g 2-batch Normal). Can it be used to define a two dimensional distribution where one dimension is a Cauchy and another Normal? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

`tfd.Blockwise` will do that for you: https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/Blockwise

Comment: Perhaps you could expand on this answer? Doing the obvious `combined = tfp.distributions.Blockwise([tfp.distributions.Normal(0, 1), tfp.distributions.Cauchy(1, 1)])` seems to result in an error